# WebApi Missing Current Classes Names and References of Linked Classes

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a result like JSON as that:

[image: Result]

I'm calling this result through;

```
localhost:53304/api/Students
```

I want to see filled classes in my Json Result and i know well its about Serializer settings here my some codes of classes and settings:

**DbContex:**

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyContext")

    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

**Student.cs**

```
[Table("Student")]
public partial class Student
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Student()
    {
        Discontinuity = new HashSet<Discontinuity>();
        Grade = new HashSet<Grade>();
        Payment = new HashSet<Payment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int? Class_Id { get; set; }

    public int? Group_Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(11)]
    public string TCno { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public bool? Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Discontinuity> Discontinuity { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grade { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payment { get; set; }
}
```

I want see my current class name at beginning on result as:

**"Students":** [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29
      ]
    }

And i want see results in foreign classes e.g. Grade[]